# Using shell command output within VI editor

Tags: shell, command-line, vi, shadow

I'm just walking my very first steps with vi-like editors and i would like to know if it's possible to insert the output of a shell command within a line when, for example, editing /etc/shadow with vipw -s

```
prueba4::16586:0:99999:7:::
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
```

My goal is to simply change the password of a user.
This is what i attempted:
1) Used cursor keys to position myself at the password digest field of the user prueba4. Then used the x command to remove every character of the old digest.
2) Hit Esc. Then typed

> :r!mkpasswd my..password my..salt

3) I get the desired output, but it's written in a new line, instead of the last space i was editing before hitting Esc, then ':'

Is it possible to write the digest where it belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:r!` command always works 'linewise', so it will not be able to insert any text *inside* a given line.

You can assign the command's results into a 'register' (vim's places to hold characters yanked, cut, etc) using:

```
:let @a=system("your_command")
```

and then place the *contents* of the register (your passed) when your cursor is in the place you want the text by using:
`<C-R>a`  when in insert mode at the location
or
`"ap`  when in normal mode on the character just to the left of the location (in this case the ':')

Comment: Thank you so much.
So many tutorials and net information refers to "cursor position" that i thought i was doing something wrong.